# How do i get rid of a parsings error in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my JS code, I'm currently trying to make a modal at the end of a "pizza page" but it is coming up "Parsing error: Unexpected token const".

```
if const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')
```

Comment: You can't put a `const` declaration in the middle of an `if` statement like that. Get rid of `if`.

Comment: thanks, I've got an issue with modals now XD